# Missing value on Access-SQL query with Left Join on two criteria

Tags: sql, join, criteria

I am having trouble with a query, and have run out of ideas for what's going on. I have a table T1:

```
StoreID Product ProductShipped
KH00137 Super   18
KH00137 Regular 12
```

And another table T2, that shares only a few of the StoreIDs:

```
StoreID Product Other data…
KH00137 Super   …
KH00137 Regular …
```

I am trying to left join to T2 on both StoreID and Product using the following query:

```
SELECT T1.StoreID, T2.StoreID, T1.Product, T1. ProductShipped
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.Product = T2.Product) AND (T1.StoreID = T2.StoreID);
```

But for some reason it doesn't display one of the fields T2 StoreID fields, even though it seems to have successfully joined to the other one:

```
T1.StoreID  T2.StoreID  T1.Product  T1.ProductShipped
KH00137                 Super       18
KH00137     KH00137     Regular     12
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that it has successfully joined.  Each of the three Non-NULL fields, in the first row of your output data, is from table1.

This indicates to me that actually there has not been a join at all.

- Test your data for blank spaces and uppercase/lowercase mis-matches.

Using `LENGTH()` type of functions may show that one string actually isn't the same as the other.  *(One `Super` may be 5 characters long, the `Super` in the other table might have a space at the end and be 6 characters long.  Or possibly something similar in the StoreID?)*

Also, this is one reason that supports ***not*** joining on text fields.  By keeping foriegn key IDs as numerics (such as integers) you don't run into this problem nearly so often, and even when you do it's really easy to debug and correct.

Good luck.

Comment: In a 'doh' moment, the product type (which I changed for the post above) has UK spelling in some places and US spelling in other places. So I've corrected it and now it joins perfectly. Will take on board the point about joining on text fields. :)